# Refile to any headline with of given TODO item types

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

My org file structure is as follows:

```
* JOB Major Project 1
** PROJECT Mini Project p
** PROJECT Mini Project q
* JOB Major Project 2
** PROJECT Mini Project x
** PROJECT Mini Project y
```

JOB and PROJECT being TODO items

I would like to be able to refile to either a JOB or a PROJECT todo item, that is, first by JOB and then by PROJECT. That is,  I want to file by TODO items of any kind, whether they are JOB or PROJECT.

I want a combination of:

```
 '(org-refile-targets '((nil :todo . "JOB"))))
```

and

```
 '(org-refile-targets '((nil :todo . "PROJECT"))))
```

I thought

```
 '(org-refile-targets '((nil :regexp . "JOB|PROJECT"))))
```

or

```
 '(org-refile-targets '((nil :regexp . "JOB\|PROJECT"))))
```

would do the trick, but I get 'no refile targets'.

All is within one org file.

Comment: Try `'((nil :todo . "PROJECT") (nil :todo . "JOB"))`. Remember `org-refile-targets` is a list of conses. Since it *is* a somewhat complicated variable, I used `customize` to set it and then looked at its values with `C-h v org-refile-targets`. Untested, but it looks like a reasonable possibility to me.

Answer (score 0):

What op is asking is how do you set org-refile-targets based multiple conditions like
todo, regexp etc... AFIK you can't do this, the solution is to use the `org-refile-target-verify-function`.

In this example we need both the `:regexp` key that matches `"README"` and `:maxlevel` 1.
You can use the function to match anything you want. In this case I use `org-get-previous-line-level`.

```lisp
(defun my/org-refile ()
"Call `org-refile' with a specific target."
(interactive)
  (let* ((orfiles org-agenda-files )
        (org-refile-target-verify-function (lambda ()
                                              (when (org-get-previous-line-level)
                                                (= (org-get-previous-line-level) 0))))
        ;; Won't work you will still see other levels, solution: use the org-refile-target-verify-function
        ;;(org-refile-targets `(,(cons orfiles (cons :regexp "README")) ,(cons orfiles (cons :maxlevel 1)))))
        (org-refile-targets `(,(cons orfiles (cons :regexp "README")))))
  (org-refile)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I *just* posted about a very similar thing with `refile`: [see my question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/79024/19526).

I've found that `org-refile-targets` can be viewed as unioning together targets, and ``org-refile-target-verify-function` filters some out.

You should be able to use multiple entries for a single file: in my own configuration, I have a certain file with a `:tag . "refile-here"` entry, and also a `:regexp` entry that matches other headings in the same file that don't have the `refile-here` tag, but (for my own idiosyncratic reasons) want to have them as a refile target. So those two entries are inclusive -- you get headings matching either one.

Separately, ``org-refile-target-verify-function` is exclusive, and can be used to filter out headings you don't want as a target.