# can org-refile-targets match headings *without* a given tag?

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

I can configure `org-refile-targets` to match headings in an org file with a certain tag. Can I do an [arbitrary tag match](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html)? I'm interested in headings *without* a certain tag.

(For example, I'd like to suppress headings with an ARCHIVE tag, or some kind of "done" or "ignore" tag.)

Comment: How would that work with refiling? Most headings would not have the tag I imagine, so refile would pick the first one of those? Even if it could be done, it doesn't seem very useful: you generally want to refile to a well-defined place.

Comment: In my particular file, most of the headings *do* have the tag that I want to ignore.

Comment: It still seems simpler to just add a `refilehere` tag to a unique headline to mark the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly the kind of tag/property search I asked about, but there is `org-refile-target-verify-function` which is called for each of the targets initially considered; you can do arbitrary logic with that function to determine if the entry should be considered a target. You can use `org-get-tags`: something involving

```
(member "sometag" (org-get-tags))
```